# How to fetch xml value from the table column(which looks like XML) dynamically and I do not know the xml tag name and that column is not of XML type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column as shown below..

```html
<div><p><span lang="ES-PR" style='background: white; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: "Roboto",serif; font-size: 10.5pt; mso-ansi-language: ES-PR;'><?xml:namespace prefix = "o" ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></span><span lang="ES-PR" style='color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: "Roboto",serif; font-size: 10pt; mso-ansi-language: ES-PR; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial;'>1. Asegurado desea saber status de investigación
de servicios de cirugía bariátrica con proveedor no participante Rafael
Iglesias, al momento de llamada, intento comunicarme con proveedor para
verificar si va facturar bajo su nombre o bajo el nombre de la facilidad, nadie
contesta llamada, &nbsp; Posteriormente, aseguradado vuelve a llamar y
representante Suheilly logra comunicarse con proveedor y se le orienta que TSA
solo pagará una parte del servicio.&nbsp;</span></p><p><span lang="ES-PR" style='color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: "Roboto",serif; font-size: 10pt; mso-ansi-language: ES-PR; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial;'>2.&nbsp; Se le orienta que debe conseguir algún
proveedor quien tenga contrato con TSA para aminorar costos. <?xml:namespace prefix = "o" ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></span></p><p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">

</font><span lang="ES-PR" style='color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: "Roboto",serif; font-size: 10pt; mso-ansi-language: ES-PR; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial;'>3. &nbsp;Asegurada habla de otro cirujano quien
conoce, el Dr. Albert Suarez Domínguez #6765 quien tiene contrato TSA active.
 Sin embargo, intento comunicarme con dicho proveedor pero nadie contesta
al 7877588340. &nbsp;Quedo en realizar gestión durante la tarde llamando
directo a la Torre del Auxilio Mutuo para transferencia directa y poder
coordinar cita para evaluación para ctp 43375, cuya es la codificación que
asegurada me brinda durante llamada. &nbsp;</span></p><p><span lang="ES-PR" style='color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: "Roboto",serif; font-size: 10pt; mso-ansi-language: ES-PR; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial;'>4.&nbsp; Se envía copia de nota a representante
callback Melissa Nieves para su debido seguimiento ya que tiene el caso asignado
en su bandeja y se encuentra bajo status "current".//Jonathan Leon</span></p></div>
```

I need the data as below using SQL query.

I am getting above data from a table column and the column is of VARCHAR type.
And one more thing to mention, I have multiple columns coming from My Database and I do not know tag names, i.e, there will be 100's of tags in different columns so, the SQL Query should with TAGS INDEPENDENTly

Output I need:

> 1. Asegurado desea saber status de investigación de servicios de cirugía bariátrica con proveedor no participante Rafael Iglesias, al
>    momento de llamada, intento comunicarme con proveedor para verificar
>    si va facturar bajo su nombre o bajo el nombre de la facilidad, nadie
>    contesta llamada,   Posteriormente, aseguradado vuelve a llamar y
>    representante Suheilly logra comunicarse con proveedor y se le orienta
>    que TSA solo pagará una parte del servicio.
> 2. Se le orienta que debe conseguir algún proveedor quien tenga contrato con TSA para aminorar costos.
> 3. Asegurada habla de otro cirujano quien conoce, el Dr. Albert Suarez Domínguez #6765 quien tiene contrato TSA active. Sin embargo,
>    intento comunicarme con dicho proveedor pero nadie contesta al
>    7877588340.  Quedo en realizar gestión durante la tarde llamando directo a la Torre del Auxilio Mutuo para transferencia directa y
>    poder coordinar cita para evaluación para ctp 43375, cuya es la
>    codificación que asegurada me brinda durante llamada.
> 4. Se envía copia de nota a representante callback Melissa Nieves para su debido seguimiento ya que tiene el caso asignado en su bandeja
>    y se encuentra bajo status "current".//Jonathan Leon

Comment: what does point 1.2.3.4 say lol

Comment: wait, my question got edited
it actually has xml tags

Comment: how can I edit my question ?

Comment: right under the tags

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48790138/edit)

Comment: Thanks Long, I have edited my question, can you please look into it and solve my question

Comment: @AnandM - I've placed the HTML in a code snippet which I believe is what you wanted to show? However, I'm still confused about what you actually want to do. The HTML posted looks very similar to your desired output.

Comment: Good luck with this. t-sql is not a good tool for trying to strip all this html out. This looks like the source of an html page. You would be better off doing this in a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done somewhat easily with a recursive CTE, though I'm not sure about performance at scale.

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX) = '<div><p><span lang="ES-PR" style="background: white; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: "Roboto",serif; font-size: 10.5pt; mso-ansi-language: ES-PR;"><?xml:namespace prefix = "o" ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></span><span lang="ES-PR" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: "Roboto",serif; font-size: 10pt; mso-ansi-language: ES-PR; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial;">1. Asegurado desea saber status de investigación
    de servicios de cirugía bariátrica con proveedor no participante Rafael
    Iglesias, al momento de llamada, intento comunicarme con proveedor para
    verificar si va facturar bajo su nombre o bajo el nombre de la facilidad, nadie
    contesta llamada, &nbsp; Posteriormente, aseguradado vuelve a llamar y
    representante Suheilly logra comunicarse con proveedor y se le orienta que TSA
    solo pagará una parte del servicio.&nbsp;</span></p><p><span lang="ES-PR" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: "Roboto",serif; font-size: 10pt; mso-ansi-language: ES-PR; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial;">2.&nbsp; Se le orienta que debe conseguir algún
    proveedor quien tenga contrato con TSA para aminorar costos. <?xml:namespace prefix = "o" ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></span></p><p><font face="Times New Roman" size="3">
    </font><span lang="ES-PR" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: "Roboto",serif; font-size: 10pt; mso-ansi-language: ES-PR; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial;">3. &nbsp;Asegurada habla de otro cirujano quien
    conoce, el Dr. Albert Suarez Domínguez #6765 quien tiene contrato TSA active.
     Sin embargo, intento comunicarme con dicho proveedor pero nadie contesta
    al 7877588340. &nbsp;Quedo en realizar gestión durante la tarde llamando
    directo a la Torre del Auxilio Mutuo para transferencia directa y poder
    coordinar cita para evaluación para ctp 43375, cuya es la codificación que
    asegurada me brinda durante llamada. &nbsp;</span></p><p><span lang="ES-PR" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-family: "Roboto",serif; font-size: 10pt; mso-ansi-language: ES-PR; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial;">4.&nbsp; Se envía copia de nota a representante
    callback Melissa Nieves para su debido seguimiento ya que tiene el caso asignado
    en su bandeja y se encuentra bajo status "current".//Jonathan Leon</span></p></div>'

;WITH Base AS (
    SELECT
        0 i
        ,SUBSTRING(@text, 0, CHARINDEX('<', @text, 0) + 1) entry
        ,SUBSTRING(@text, CHARINDEX('>', @text, 0) + 1, LEN(@text)) remaining
), Recurse AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM Base
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        i + 1 i
        ,SUBSTRING(remaining, 0, CHARINDEX('<', remaining, 0)) entry
        ,SUBSTRING(remaining, CHARINDEX('>', remaining, 0) + 1, LEN(@text)) remaining
    FROM Recurse WHERE LEN(Remaining) > 0
)

SELECT REPLACE(STUFF((
    SELECT
        RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(entry, '&nbsp;',''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '')) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)
    FROM Recurse
    WHERE LEN(entry) > 3
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 0, ''), '&#x0D;', '')
```

Comment: Also, this would absolutely be better/faster using regex in a programming language that can iterate better than TSQL.

Comment: Thanks @Binary Patrick, 
but the thing is, the output is coming in multiple rows but I need it in a single row as I have passed input as a single record.

Comment: Ok, that's acomplished easily enough with `FOR XML PATH('')` and `STUFF()`. I've updated the code above to include both.